# Variable names for designdoc and view in couchdb

Tags: python-3.x, couchdb

New to couchdb.  For this hardcoding the name of Design doc and view name works. Is it possible to give a variable for it?

```
server = couchdb.Server( url)
db = server['test']
for docid in db.view('Res/res'):
    i = docid['key']
```

The above code works but i want to use this code in a loop
i tried the below code. but its giving me error

for docid in db.view(map.cityname+"/"+city):

Comment: Of course, why not? What problems do you encounter when you try?

Comment: It gives me ResourceNotFound error...
('not_found', 'missing_named_view')

Comment: Then you're sending an empty view name.